# systemd-networkd: enp0s8: DHCP: No gateway received from DHCP server

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, dhcp, c#, reverse-proxy

I am setting up a server with the following configurations:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- C# .NET Core 5.0 Framework, not runtime
- Apache 2.4.41
- All running on VirtualBox VM

I have built and deployed an example project that comes with Visual Studio, and that works without issue locally.

When I try to access the site I get the following error:

```
 systemd-networkd[678]: enp0s8: DHCP: No gateway received from DHCP server.
```

Here is my set up:
The domain does not exist outside of my dev environment. I have added it to my host file.

- Apache config: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxxxx.config - This is what I have after trying many combinations and using /etc/apache2/config-enable/xxxxx.config. So, I am not sure whether I should be using config or site. It seems the current set up is better now than where I first started.

  ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       #ServerName xxx.xxxxx.com
       ServerName localhost
       ServerAlias xxx.xxxxx.com
       ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
       RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P]
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/xxxxx-error.log
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xxxxx-access.log common
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Service file /etc/system/system/xxxxx.service - I tried different combination here as well, and this is my last version.

  ```
   [Unit]
   Description=service description
   [Service]
   WorkingDirectory=/var/www/xxxxx
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/xxxxx/xxxxx.dll
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=10
   KillSignal=SIGINT
   SyslogIdentifier=xxxxx
   User=www-data
   Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

## ip route show

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.104
```

Comment: You have configured `enp0s8` to obtain it's IP address from a DHCP server. The DHCP server did not set a "gateway", a system to which you can send packets. Fix the DHCP server. For now, read `man ip ip-route arp`. `ip route show` to see current routing.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].